# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined in Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html

I have this Javascript function butwhen i run it it says 'Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at showSlides'

```
 var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: I suppose the error is from `slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; ` . Try console logging your `slideIndex` just before this line

Comment: @Zenoo at the very top of the snippet

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, it slipped through my reading.

Comment: @Ernest Des-Bordes Do you always have at least one element with class mySlides? Because if you don't then when you are assigning block it will give you an error.

Comment: @Ernest Des-Bordes please share the html also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length - 1}
```

`slideIndex` cannot be `slides.length`, The last element of `slides` will be present at `slides.length - 1`, not `slides.length`.